# Cant implement method

Tags: java, android, oncreate

I want to implement the following method:

```
public void setButtons(Button b, int h, int w){
    b.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(w, h));
}
```

in my onCreate method:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++){
        public void setButtons(buttons[i], widthOfButtons, widthOfButtons);
    }
```

but i get errors, ive been trying to figure out whats wrong for a while, but im fairly new to java and i feel like this code just needs someone elses eyes so can someone please tell me how to implement the above method properly? Thanks.

**EDIT**

adding more code:
below is where i initialize the array:

```
   Button[] buttons = new Button[23];
    buttons[0] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.alef);
    buttons[1] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.beis);
    buttons[3] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.gimmel);
    buttons[4] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.daled);
    buttons[5] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.heh);
    buttons[6] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.vav);
    buttons[7] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.zayin);
    buttons[7] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ches);
    buttons[8] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tes);
    buttons[9] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.yud);
    buttons[10] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.chaf);
    buttons[11] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.lamed);
    buttons[12] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mem);
    buttons[13] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nun);
    buttons[14] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ayin);
    buttons[15] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.peh);
    buttons[16] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tzadi);
    buttons[17] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.kuf);
    buttons[18] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reish);
    buttons[19] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.shin);
    buttons[20] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.taf);
    buttons[21] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.empty1);
    buttons[22] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.empty2);
    buttons[23] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.empty3);
```

and here is the full class that i declare method:

```
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;


public class initButtons {

    public void setButtons(Button b, int h, int w){
        b.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(w, h));
    }
}
```

Comment: What errors? Seems like useful information. But obviously you can't implement a method inside another one. Maybe you mean to add a handler to each button?

Comment: it says that "; expected" and "unexpected tokens" and i cant seem to see whats wrong

Comment: because that's not how you call a method in java. See any one of the answers below.

Comment: @DaveNewton ohhhh i totally forgot that im in middle of another method- thanks im  newbie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace below line from onCreate

```
public void setButtons(buttons[i], widthOfButtons, widthOfButtons);
```

By

```
new initButtons().setButtons(buttons[i], widthOfButtons, widthOfButtons);
```

OR By

```
initButtons iButton = new initButtons();
iButton.setButtons(buttons[i], widthOfButtons, widthOfButtons);
```

Comment: i tried that and now im getting error that says "method call expected"

Comment: @Isaac, You should post a bit more of your code, so we can see what is wrong with it.

Comment: @Isaac I updated the code please check. You were writing the method under a class So for this you have to instantiate the class and then you can call that class method

Answer (score 0):

Call method like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++){
            setButtons(buttons[i], widthOfButtons, widthOfButtons);
        }
```

Comment: okay i did that and all errors went away except higlight under method name that "cannot resolve method ..." please help!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot declare a function inside a For loop. The `public void setButtons(buttons[i], widthOfButtons, widthOfButtons);` is a declaration. Besides, there is no body in your function. Try to change the line to `setButtons(buttons[i], widthOfButtons, widthOfButtons);` and add a function in your code:

```
public void setButtons(buttons[i], widthOfButtons, widthOfButtons) {
   doSomething...

}
```